# Creating instance for core data class iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, restkit

I have a coredata class with a base class as `NSManagedObject`. I am using this class for storing data which are fetched from the server. I am storing it using Restkit Object Mapping. I am using same class for sending input to the server. For that I have created a `classA(NSObject)`, in which I created an instance for my core data class. I am passing object of `classA`. I can able to retrieve the data and store it into coredata using Restkit.

Problem:

- When I try to fetch the details from database. I am getting 4 Values(actual value is 3 which is returned from server). From that one object becomes nil. I don't know the exact reason.
- I think the problem is with my core data instance. How can I create a instance for Core data class.

Note: when I view my db, it shows only 3 rows. I think there is no problem with saving data in db.

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [ClassA fetchRequest]; //ClassA is core data class
NSSortDescriptor* descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"locationName" 
                                                             ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

NSArray* Objects = [GHSLocation objectsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

Thanks